# How to make Array to Variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have some array looks like this:

```js
const [listArr, setLA]= useState([
    {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random * 100000),
      data: "This is data 1",
    },
    {
      id: Math.floor(Math.random * 100000),
      data: "This is data 2",
    },
    ....(and so on)
  ]);
```

and i need to extract those `data` to become `1 variable` and get it using console looks like

```
console.log(data);
//This is data 1\nThis is data2
```

I've tried using foreach to put 1 by 1 but still didn't work, can you guys help me?

Comment: What do you mean by one variable? Could you specify more what should be done?

Comment: Try `console.log(listArr.map(({ data }) => data).join('\n'))`

Comment: DUDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE @HaoWu you are awesome, please put this on answer column

Comment: Hey @RajeshPaudel thanks for your comment, i'm sorry, i'll try to specify more later..

Comment: @HaksatryaBhaswara Sure :) glad it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to get an array of the values you want and then [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them into a string in order to print to the console:

```js
console.log(listArr.map(({ data }) => data).join('\n'))
```